# How to cast a dynamic object to a type and compare

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, salesforce

I have a model called products,

```
public class Product
{                 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Sku { get; set; }

    public float Cost { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }        
}
```

I will get a list of objects as type dynamic from externel source as follows

```
string query = "SELECT Id,Name,KNDYCPQ__Description__c,KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c FROM KNDY4__Product__c";
List<dynamic> products = new List<dynamic>();
products = await SalesforceSyncProvider.QueryAsync(query);
foreach (var x in products)
{
    Product product = new Product();
    if (db.Products.Where(a => a.Sku ==x.KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c).FirstOrDefault() != null) {

    product.Name = x.Name;
    product.Sku = x.KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c;
    product.Description = x.KNDYCPQ__Description__c;
    product.Cost = 2000;
    db.Products.Add(product);
    }
}
```

So, before adding to my db, I want to check the product code (`KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c`) with my `Sku` for avoiding duplicates but the if condition is failing and showing the error that, an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.

Comment: put `x.KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c` in a strongly typed variable and use that in the expression..

Comment: exception messages are our friends, they contains answers for almost **all** our questions. Too bad, that nobody really reads them:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `x.KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c` in a strongly typed variable and use that in the expression.

```
string sku = x.KNDYCPQ__ProductCode__c;

if (db.Products.Where(a => a.Sku == sku).FirstOrDefault() != null) {

//...
```